# "whenever" gem is generating illegal crontab syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, cron, whenever

I'm using the [`whenever` gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for my crontab scheduling.  The syntax being generated is incorrect.  Below you will notice it is adding these quotes and forward slashes`'\''AddressGeocodeWorker.perform_async'\''`

Incorrect crontab

`0 4 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/lib/streetcred/agency/releases/streetcred && bin/rails runner -e production '\''AddressGeocodeWorker.perform_async'\'''`

Correct crontab would look like this

`0 4 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/lib/streetcred/agency/releases/streetcred && bin/rails runner -e production AddressGeocodeWorker.perform_async'`

schedule.rb

`every 1.day, :at => '4:00 am' do
  runner "AddressGeocodeWorker.perform_async"
end`

How would I get `whenever` to generate the correct crontab entry?

Comment: What's wrong with the first one?  It will parse just fine by cron.  All of mine look that way.

Comment: Why do you believe that first crontab entry is incorrect? That's how you embed single-quotes inside a single-quoted string. (That happens to not be necessary in this case and so could be simplified to the second example but should work just fine I would think.)

Comment: Ya it doesnt work on our server though, I thought that it was illegal syntax.